# Content of Div Wrapper Won't Center (Horizontal Align)

Tags: css, html, alignment, wrapper

I've been trying to figure out forever now why my wrapper div (#searchContents) that I want to use to center four items (text [#inputPrompt], input box [#accountName], submit button [#submit], loading image [#wait]) inside another div (#searchBox) won't work properly.

Here's the HTML:

```html
<div id="searchBox">
        <div id="searchContents">
            <span id="inputPrompt">Account Name:</span> <input type="text"
                id="accountName" />
            <button id="submit">Submit</button>
            <img id="wait" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```css
#searchBox {
    background-color: #181818;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #383838;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#searchContents {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#inputPrompt {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 16px;
}
#accountName {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
#submit {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
#wait {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

The "#searchContents" is the wrapper, so I set the margin-left and margin-right properties to horizontally align everything within the wrapper, but it still seems to all be left-aligned.

Can anyone point me to the issue and the solution?

Here's a fiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/T58rc/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to center the content of `#searchContents` try `text-align: center`

```
#searchContents {
    text-align: center
}
```

This will apply to `inline` and `inline-block` elements.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/T58rc/4/)**

---

You can use `margin: 0 auto` in order to center `#searchContents` inside its parent but then you need to specify a width for `#searchContents` in order for margin auto to work.

Comment: If I do width: 100% it still doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: It's already centered. But only the `div` itself, not it's contents

Comment: Your title confused me. It should maybe say content of wrapper

Comment: @Pinki `#searchContents` is a div so it should be `display: block` by default. But like I said, I misunderstodd the question as wasn't the wrapper that should be centered but the content of the wrapper.

Comment: @Mathias Hm looks like it may have, assuming you meant set #searchContents to text-align: center?  
  
**EDIT** - Just saw your updated answer, I think this works.

Comment: @Mathias Kind of unrelated to the original question, but do you know how I could make it so the #searchBox is only as wide as it needs to be?  
If I remove the width property, it fills up the entire width of the page which is not what I want.

Comment: @Mark Then you are venturing into a whole new set of problems, which can be solved in different ways. This solution should work in IE8+ http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/T58rc/5/. It uses `display: inline-block` for `#searchContents` and `text-align: center` for `#searchBox`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="page">
        <div id="searchBox">
            <div id="searchContents"> <span id="inputPrompt">Steam Account:</span> 
                <input type="text" id="steamName" />
                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
                <img id="wait" src="http://darkstrikerd.files.wordpress.com/2011/08/load.gif" alt="Loading..." />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    color: white;
}
#page {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#searchBox {
    background-color: #181818;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #383838;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-top: 5%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right : auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#searchContents {
    width: auto;
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#inputPrompt {
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 16px;
}
#steamName {
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 16px;
    height: 16px;
}
#submit {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}
#wait {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RBfmH/4/)

NOTE: I've added width: 400px; to the #searchContents You can add another width, but it's nessesary to add a width when you're using `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: I'd like to keep the width to percentage so that it's as dynamic as possible, seems like using your method with a percentage width doesn't work though.

Comment: You can use width: auto; max-width and min-width instead, that's really dynamic too.

Comment: You can use CSS @media-queries to make it really dynamic and mobile friendly. http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: I used your suggestion for min-width to make sure my div doesn't shrink to the point that items inside it get pushed to a new line, thanks for the info